# Ссылки почему-то открываются в новых вкладках (без target="_blank")

Tags: tabs, .htaccess, html, link

Здравствуйте.

Почему-то ссылки стали открываться в новых вкладках, несмотря на то, что `target="_blank"` не прописан нигде. Мне пришлось средствами JS прописать во всех ссылках и формах атрибут `«target="_self"»`. Но это - "костыли". Я не понимаю, почему так происходит. Может, что-то не так в htaccess? Вот проблемный сайт: http://znaydu.com

Comment: @9poIIIa Спасибо! Я же "решил" проблему "костылями", через JS прописав attr target="_self"

Answer (score 1):

проблема в html теге

```
<base target="http://znaydu.com/">
```

он должен быть

```
<base href="http://znaydu.com/">
```